# Transferring data to a new Mac

Tags: mac, software-rec, file-transfer

I just got a **new Mac** laptop, and I'm looking to transfer some data from my old Mac to this one. I'd like recommendations on **what to transfer** and **how** to do it. (I'm making this a community wiki question, so please add on your own suggestions.) I'm not looking for a direct transfer, but rather a minimal organizational strategy to get old data into a fresh install.

These are the things I think I'll need to transfer:

- Documents
- Developer tools & projects
- Sites folder
- iTunes library / iPhone/iPad backups & settings
- Applications
- Fonts

So, for now the question is how to go about doing this. Does anyone have experience transferring iTunes libraries and iOS device stuff — should I just copy the `~/Music/iTunes` folder or is there more involved?

For documents, fonts, applications, and developer stuff, it seems the best strategy is just to transfer the files directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Migration Assistant in your /Applications/Utilities folder. It's very good and should get everything. Anything it misses, you'd probably want to copy over manually anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have different suggestions depending on your level of "acquaintance" with the system. For instance, if you'd like an App with a GUI and all that, you can try "CarbonCopy" and just make a copy of your home folder, '/Users/yourusername'. On the other hand, if you're more advanced at the console, you can simply use 'tar' and mirror all of your stuff this way. (My personal strategy is this last one: tar everything to an external HD and be done with it.)

On a slightly tangential note, if you use Apple's favorite backup method, "Time Machine", you probably don't need to do anything, other than keeping your backups up-to-date. ;-)

Finally, as far as the Apps are concerned, i'd just re-install them — although, in principle, there's no problem in simply mirroring everything with 'tar' or 'CarbonCopy', for that matter.